# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume pvc, mount failed: exit status 32

Tags: mount, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

We are trying to configure vsphere cloud provider for kubernetes cluster according to below support link for dynamic provisioning from vmware. There was  no problem with kubernetres version  v1.8, the issue appeared after deploying new kubernetes cluster with version 1.12.
https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-storage-for-kubernetes/documentation/existing.html

**Kubernetes version**
`v1.12.7`

**Environment**
`Cluster:   master1,node1,node2`
`Virtualization:   VMware ESXi, 6.5.0, 7388607 , each virtual machine node placed on different esxi host, diskuuid is true`
`Network:   Cisco Apic, Version 3.2(4e)`

**Problem definition:**
`Storage class, pv, pvc successfull created and bounded, vmdk disk added to virtual machine successfully but node cannot mount this physical disk to virtual path of the pod, there are two different log not sure which one is right, first log mention _"cloud provider not initialized"_, if not how vmdk created and attached to virtual machine, second log mention _"mount failed because not found the ...vmdk"_ but i can browse from the vcenter mentioned vmdk is in the datastore"`

```
[root@kubemaster ~]# kubectl get pods pvpod
NAME    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pvpod   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          17h
```

**kubectl descrice pod pvpod**

```
[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl describe pod pvpod
Name:               pvpod
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  
Node:               kubenode2/10.1.1.12
Start Time:         Tue, 14 May 2019 12:52:18 +0300
Labels:             
Annotations:        opflex.cisco.com/computed-endpoint-group: {"policy-space":"Kubernetes","name":"kubernetes|kube-default"}
                    opflex.cisco.com/computed-security-group: []
Status:             Pending
IP:
Containers:
  test-container:
    Container ID:
    Image:          gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    Image ID:
    Port:           
    Host Port:      
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    
    Mounts:
      /test-vmdk from test-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-pvf97 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  test-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  pvcsc001
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-pvf97:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-pvf97
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age    From                           Message
  ----     ------       ----   ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled    8m22s  default-scheduler              Successfully assigned default/pvpod to kubenode2
  Warning  FailedMount  8m21s  kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3
Output: Running scope as unit run-87284.scope.
mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist
  Warning  FailedMount  8m21s  kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3
Output: Running scope as unit run-87288.scope.
mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist
  Warning  FailedMount  8m20s  kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3
Output: Running scope as unit run-87290.scope.
mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist
  Warning  FailedMount  8m18s  kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f63bb16e-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3
Output: Running scope as unit run-87329.scope.
mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  8m17s  attachdetach-controller        AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3"
  Warning  FailedMount             8m14s  kubelet, kubenode2  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-eb27986d-762d-11e9-aff9-005056b068e3" : mount failed: exit status 32
```

**/var/log/messages  on the node**

```
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: E0508 16:05:32.730158   53933 vsphere_volume_util.go:187] Cloud provider not initialized properly
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 systemd: Started Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3.
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: E0508 16:05:32.744639   53933 mount_linux.go:152] Mount failed: exit status 32
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: Mounting command: systemd-run
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: Output: Running scope as unit run-57611.scope.
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: E0508 16:05:32.744865   53933 nestedpendingoperations.go:267] Operation for "\"kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\" (\"b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\")" failed. No retries permitted until 2019-05-08 16:07:34.74479901 +0300 +03 m=+619.028655111 (durationBeforeRetry 2m2s). Error: "MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume \"pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\") pod \"pvpod\" (UID: \"b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\") : mount failed: exit status 32\nMounting command: systemd-run\nMounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3 --scope -- mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3.vmdk /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b52b1433-718a-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3/volumes/kubernetes.io~vsphere-volume/pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3\nOutput: Running scope as unit run-57611.scope.\nmount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume/mounts/[KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-e3705fec-7189-11e9-a3ef-005056b068e3.vmdk does not exist\n\n"
May  8 16:05:32 kubenode1 kubelet: E0508 16:05:32.830478   53933 vsphere_volume_util.go:187] Cloud provider not initialized properly
```

**Pv,PVC,SC yaml files**

`Sc-fast.yaml`

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata: 
  name: fast
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
parameters: 
  datastore: KUBEDATASTORE
  diskformat: thin
  fstype: ext3

pvc.yaml

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvcsc001
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi

pod.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pvpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test-volume
      mountPath: /test-vmdk
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: pvcsc001

**Output of applied yaml files**

`[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl create -f vsphere-volume-sc-fast.yaml
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/fast created
[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl describe storageclass fast
Name:                  fast
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Parameters:            datastore=KUBEDATASTORE,diskformat=thin,fstype=ext3
AllowVolumeExpansion:  
MountOptions:          
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:`

[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl create -f vsphere-volume-pvcsc.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/pvcsc001 created
[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl describe pvc pvcsc001
Name:          pvcsc001
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  fast
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-4aa82312-72ec-11e9-8b74-005056b068e3
Labels:        
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      2Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
Events:
  Type       Reason                 Age   From                         Message
  Normal     ProvisioningSucceeded  13s   persistentvolume-controller  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-4aa82312-72ec-11e9-8b74-005056b068e3 using kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Mounted By: <.none>

[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl describe pv  pvc-4aa82312-72ec-11e9-8b74-005056b068e3
Name:            pvc-4aa82312-72ec-11e9-8b74-005056b068e3
Labels:          
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/createdby: vsphere-volume-dynamic-provisioner
                 pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                 pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    fast
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/pvcsc001
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        2Gi
Node Affinity:   
Message:
Source:
    Type:               vSphereVolume (a Persistent Disk resource in vSphere)
    VolumePath:         [KUBEDATASTORE] kubevols/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-4aa82312-72ec-11e9-8b74-005056b068e3.vmdk
    FSType:             ext3
    StoragePolicyName:
Events:

`[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]# kubectl create -f vsphere-volume-pvcscpod.yaml
pod/pvpod created
[root@kubemaster vcp]#
[root@kubemaster vcp]#  kubectl get pod pvpod
NAME    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pvpod   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          49s`

**first progress**

in the first place when i run “ vsphere-volume-pvcsc.yaml”  it was not successfully creating the volume, output of the “kubectl describe pvc” message was *No VM found*, than i applied https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65933#issuecomment-408358655  method to match uuids( even providerid and product serial was same), after than volume created successfully and attached into virtual machine. But Pod still ContainerCreating state.

cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial | sed -e 's/^VMware-//' -e 's/-/ /' | awk '{ print toupper($1$2$3$4 "-" $5$6 "-" $7$8 "-" $9$10 "-" $11$12$13$14$15$16) }'
kubectl patch node kubemaster -p '{"spec":{"providerID":"vsphere://4230456E-D8B2-AED1-E270-740256CBD273"}}'

**Second progress**

We have disgussed with @shahbour at #77663 and we made sure it is not a cloud provider issue even the message "cloud provider not initialized properly" message take to the stage while container creating.

Answer (score 0):

This comment was mistake  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77663#issuecomment-493453846, i again focused on cloud provider config according to @divyenpatel comment

Reconfiguring **kubelet** and **10-kubeadm.conf** files as below than  **systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet**  fixed the problem.

`/etc/sysconfig/kubelet , i have added node-ip parameter because uncommenting EXTRA_ARG from 10-kubelet.conf was causing node status to Not Ready`

```
**<on the master node>**
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=vsphere --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/pki/vsphere.conf --node-ip 10.1.1.10

**<on the worker nodes>**
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cloud-provider=vsphere --node-ip 10.1.1.11
```

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.servide.d/10-kubeadm.conf , i have added cloud-provider parameters also in KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS, Notice that vsphere path doesnt needed on worker nodes, it is for master only`

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--cloud-provider=vsphere --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/pki/vsphere.conf --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

I dont know why below log message start appearing on the nodes even problem fixed, i ll open another issue about.

```
 kubelet: W0520 10:41:04.360268   37697 vsphere.go:577] Failed to patch IP as MAC address "02:42:af:cc:*:*" does not belong to a VMware platform
```

Thanks a lot